# Rails auto round millisecond query from postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I had a problem when i query `exponent value` from `Postgresql` database.

When i query as follow:

```
select t,v from c1.hour where f = 22 and date_trunc('day',t - '1 hour'::INTERVAL) = '2016-02-26 00:00:00' order by t ;


      t          |      v      
---------------------+-------------
 2016-02-26 02:00:00 | 1.45642e+09
```

It return exponent value.

And i expand exponent values as follow:

```
select t,to_char(v, '99999999999999999D99') from c1.hour where f = 22 and date_trunc('day',t - '1 hour'::INTERVAL) = '2016-02-26 00:00:00' order by t ;
      t          |      to_char       
---------------------+--------------------
 2016-02-26 02:00:00 | 1456418944
```

But when i used `ActiveRecord` to get data, the result seems incorrect.

```
#<Aws1:0x00000007940ca8 t: Fri, 26 Feb 2016 02:00:00 JST +09:00, f: 22, v: 1456420000.0>
```

**My expected result is:** `1456418944` instead of `1456420000.0`.

And i didn't understand why `Rails` returned this result. Can I get some help on this please?

**Some information**: I used `Rails 4.2.5`, `Ruby 2.2.3` and `gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'`

Update: This is hour table

```
aws1=# \d hour
             Table "c1.hour"
Column |            Type             | Modifiers 
--------+-----------------------------+-----------
t      | timestamp without time zone | not null
f      | smallint                    | not null
h      | smallint                    | not null
v      | real                        | 
q      | smallint                    | 
Indexes:
"hour_key" PRIMARY KEY, btree (t, f, h)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, `Aws1` is model of table c1.hour. My first query is same value with this. But i want to get real value as second query.

Comment: Yes, i only type `Aws1.where(f: 22).order(t: :desc).first` and it will return above record.

Comment: What type is column `v`? Can you show us the output of `\d c1.hour`?

Comment: Sorry, i updated my table hour. Please refresh your browser. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a PostgreSQL issue, not Rails. Rails just shows what was returned. It won’t adjust the query result by any means. As I can see, when PG is queried for this field explicitly, it returns `1.45642e+09`, which is apparently exactly equals to what you see in Rails (`1456420000.0`.)

So, the question is to be restated as “how would one force PG to return a precise value?” Well, you have this question answered in OP: explicit type convertion `to_char(v, '99999999999999999D99')` is needed.

The summing up: there are two solutions I can think of:

- introduce the new calculated field in PG, filled up by trigger as `to_char(v, '99999999999999999D99')`, or
- use an explicit query in Rails.

The latter would look like:

```
Aws1.connection.execute %Q{
  SELECT t, to_char(v, '99999999999999999D99')
  FROM c1.hour
  WHERE f = 22 
    AND date_trunc('day',t - '1 hour'::INTERVAL) = '2016-02-26 00:00:00'
  ORDER BY t
}
```

Comment: Thank for your response. 
I totally agree with your answer, but i used as `Aws1.find_by_sql("...")`.

Comment: Yes, `Aws1.find_by_sql("...")` is even better.